# Composer symlink dependency of dependency

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-nova

I am trying to work on a subdependency. This is the package structure:

`my-project` > `nova-impersonate` > `laravel-impersonate`.

At first, I just added `laravel-impersonate` to my require-dev and set `dev-master` as version, but that clashed with the `^1.2` version in `nova-impersonate`.

So I also cloned the `nova-impersonate`, and updated the version to `dev-master`. I also added both these repos to my `composer.json`.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../laravel-impersonate"
    },
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../nova-impersonate"
    }
],
```

Upon installing, composer outputs:

> Installing lab404/laravel-impersonate (dev-master 05fc39f): Downloading (100%)
>
> Installing kabbouchi/nova-impersonate (dev-master): Symlinking from ../nova-impersonate

So, the `laravel-impersonate` is not being symlinked, it is being loaded from Github instead.

How can I symlink a dependency of one of my dependencies?

**Edit:**

I have updated my `composer.json` according to [rob004s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036823/composer-symlink-dependency-of-dependency#comment98720699_56036823).

```
"require": {
    // ...
    "kabbouchi/nova-impersonate": "^1.0",
    "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "dev-master as 1.2"
},
"repositories": [
    // ...
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../laravel-impersonate"
    }
],
```

In my `composer.lock`, I can still see the following:

```
"name": "lab404/laravel-impersonate",
"version": "dev-master",
"dist": {
    "type": "zip",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/404labfr/laravel-impersonate/zipball/05fc39ff90430aaec35553c12d94121356a6af7a",
     "reference": "05fc39ff90430aaec35553c12d94121356a6af7a",
     "shasum": ""
 },
```

Comment: You may use `dev-master as 1.2.0` to avoid cloning of `nova-impersonate`.

Comment: What does the requirement in each `composer.json` (my-project & nova-impersonate) for `lab404/laravel-impersonate` look like?

Comment: @rob006 Your suggestion seems smart. I've read some about it here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md

However, removing `nova-impersonate` and using `dev-master as 1.2.0` is not working. I've updated my question.